# Trying to pass a an array_map inside a class. Its returning null.

Tags: php

I have a class with 2 functions. One function has the array map that pass the array to another function within the same class. Unfortunatly the array is dumped as NULL. Any fix?

```
class filter
    {

      public function filt($value)
      {
        $value =  mysql_escape_string($value);
        $value = trim($value);
         return $value;

      }
        public function passover($variables)
      {
        $variables = array_map("filt",$variables);
        return $variables;

       }

    }
  $filter = new filter();

  $m=    $filter->passover($arr =array('smith'=>1, 'smith'=>2));
      var_dump($m);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide an object method as callback, you need a different syntax:

```
array_map(array($this, 'filt'), $variables)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php